# Find base of exp function within the range of summation

Tags: summation, exponential-function

I got a [sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequence) where the [relation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recurrence_relation) between elements of the sequence is given by:
\begin{align}
y_1 &= b \\
y_{i+1} &= 2 y_i + b \quad (i \in \mathbb{N})
\end{align}
where $b$ is called base, $y$ is the sequence value, and $i$ is the $i$-th element of the sequence.

For $b=1$ we could write $y_i$ as
$$ 
y_i = 2^i - 1
$$

The threshold  $t$ is a summation of every $y$ value from $x=1$ to $ x= 10$.
This is an example if $b=1$: 
$$
t 
= \sum_{i=1}^{10} y(i) 
= y(1) + y(2) + y(3) + \dotsb + y(10) 
= \sum_{i=1}^{10} (2^i-1)
$$

How would I find the base $b$ if I had the threshold $t$?

Comment: Can you elaborate on exactly what the base is? Or are is this all the information given? It's hard to generalize it if we don't have an idea of how the base concretely connects with the threshold and the equation you're summing over.

Comment: @mvw I'm not sure what you mean but I believe so. y is always equal to 2(y-1) + 1, so in the example, the Base being 1, would get multiplied by 2 and added 1 as X goes up. which would give the equation given above.

Sorry I'm no vector scientist, I know only the basics.

Comment: I understand pretty much all of it but the last one, isn't $\sum_{i=1}^{10}+y(i)$ the same as $y(1) + y(2) + ..... y(10)?$

Comment: @mvw I know how summation works but you put it in the last equation. Isn't redundant? Since they mean the same thing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how to systematically find a solution:

Your sequence is a [non-homogeneous linear recurrence with constant coefficients](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recurrence_relation#Solving_non-homogeneous_linear_recurrence_relations_with_constant_coefficients).
From
$$
y_{i+1}= 2 y_i + b
$$
one can deduce
$$
y_{i+2} = 2 y_{i+1} + b
$$
so for the difference we have
$$
y_{i+2} - y_{i+1} = 2 y_{i+1} + b - (2 y_i + b) = 2 y_{i+1} - 2 y_i
$$
or
\begin{align}
y_{i+2} &= 3 y_{i+1} - 2 y_i \iff \\
y_i &= 3 y_{i-1} - 2 y_{i-2}
\end{align}
The last equation is a [homogeneous linear recurrence with constant coefficients](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constant-recursive_sequence).

It has the characteristic equation
$$
\lambda^2 - 3 \lambda + 2 = 0 \iff \\
(\lambda - 3/2)^2 = 9/4 - 2 = 1/4 
$$
with roots $\lambda = (3 \pm 1)/2 \in \{ 1, 2 \}$.
This gives the solution
$$
y_i = k_1 1^i + k_2 2^i
$$
Inserting the first two values $y_1 = b$ and $y_2 = 2 y_1 + b = 2 b + b = 3b$ we have the system
$$
b = k_1 + 2 k_2 \\
3b = k_1 + 4 k_2
$$
which gives $2b = 2 k_2$ or $k_2 = b$ and $b = k_1 + 2 b$ or $k_1 = -b$.
This gives the solution
$$
y_i = b \, 2^i- b = b (2^i - 1)
$$

Then your threshold is
\begin{align}
t 
&= \sum_{i=1}^{10} y_i \\
&= \sum_{i=1}^{10} b (2^i - 1) \\
&= b \sum_{i=1}^{10} (2^i - 1) \\
&= b \left( \left( \sum_{i=1}^{10} 2^i \right) - \sum_{i=1}^{10} 1 \right) \\
&= b \left( \left( \frac{2^{10+1}-1}{2 - 1} - 1 \right) - 10 \right) \\
&= b ((2047 - 1) - 10) \\
&= 2036 \, b
\end{align}
where we used the formula for the [geometric series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series#Formula) with $q=2$,
$$
S(q) = \sum_{k=0}^n q^k = \frac{q^{n+1}-1}{q - 1}
$$
starting at $k = 1$ instead of $k = 0$.

This gives
$$
b = \frac{t}{2036}
$$

Answer (score 0):

Note that for general $b$, $y_i=b(2^i-1)$. Thus, $t=b\sum_{i=1}^{10}(2^i-1)=2036\cdot b$.

Comment: Define *general* b?

Comment: Whatever you set $y_1$ equal to. In your post, $y_1=b$ was defined to be your base.

Comment: holy moly I think it's working.